# QbitTorrent: don't download certain file names

Tags: qbittorrent

I don't know why, but those "torrent downloaded from" files annoy me.

Is there any way to define a string (preferably with wildcards) and prevent QbitTorrent from downloading any files containing that string?

Worst case, if the file, or part of it, is downloaded along with part of another file, then, when it is determined that the download is complete, delete the file.

Perhaps here? But, how (on Windows 10)? Please note that I have all incomplete downloads in one directory and auto-move them to a structured directory tree when complete.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Qbittorrent has added this features in this pull request: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/pull/17106

Its available in version 4.5 or newer

Now all you have to do is go to Options > Downloads > Excluded file names

Use newlines to separate multiple entries. You can use wildcards as outlined below.
`*`: matches zero or more of any characters.
`?`: matches any single character.
`[...]`: sets of characters can be represented in square brackets.\

Examples

`*.exe`: filter '.exe' file extension.
`readme.txt`: filter exact file name.
`?.txt`: filter 'a.txt', 'b.txt' but not 'aa.txt'.
`readme[0-9].txt`: filter 'readme1.txt', 'readme2.txt' but not 'readme10.txt'